# ASP .NET Textbox Values & jQuery math

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asynchronous, multiplication, addition

I'd like to do some simple addition and multiplication with ASP .NET textboxes and jQuery, if possible.

Quantity One: `<asp:Textbox ID="txtQuantity1" runat="server" />`

Quantity Two: `<asp:Textbox ID="txtQuantity2" runat="server" />`

Total Quantity: `<asp:Textbox ID="txtTotalQuantity" runat="server" ReadOnly="true" />`

Price: `<asp:Textbox ID="txtPrice" runat="server" ReadOnly="true" Text="5.00" />`

Total Order: `<asp:Textbox ID="txtTotalOrder" runat="server" ReadOnly="true" />`

I'd like the user to enter quantity 1 and quantity 2 in the text boxes and the script to add those quantities then multiply by price for total order asynchronously.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks.

Edit - tried this, no luck:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var total = (parseInt($('#<%= txtQuantity1.ClientID %>').val()) + parseInt($('#<%= txtQuantity2.ClientID %>').val())) * parseInt($('#<%= txtPrice.ClientID %>').val()); ct100_BodyContent_txtTotalOrder.initialvalue = total;
//]]>
</script>
```

Comment: @Town Thanks for the formatting assist

Comment: no problem :) You're using `initialvalue` in that code you posted, which doesn't exist. Use `value` instead and you might have more success, or simply `alert(total)` at that point to check you're getting the correct calculation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close.  Here's what I got to work:

```
    var total = (parseInt($('#<%= txtQuantity1.ClientID %>').val()) + parseInt($('#<%= txtQuantity2.ClientID %>').val()))
         * parseInt($('#<%= txtPrice.ClientID %>').val());
    $('#<%=txtTotalOrder.ClientID %>').val(total);
```

Comment: I'm missing something then, no dice for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var total = (parseInt($('#<%= txtQuantity1.ClientID %>').val()) + parseInt($('#<%= txtQuantity2.ClientID %>').val())) * parseInt($('#<%= txtPrice.ClientID %>').val());
```

Comment: Trying with parseInt(), no luck yet.

Comment: @williamdnapier: `initialvalue` doesn't exist, it should be simply `value`.